# I cannot initialize Flutter for web after adding flavors to my project

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a Flutter project that currently builds for iOS and Android. I created the project around Flutter v1.9 or so. Since creating the project, I have added flavor support to my project (dev, prod) via the guide found [here](https://medium.com/@animeshjain/build-flavors-in-flutter-android-and-ios-with-different-firebase-projects-per-flavor-27c5c5dac10b)

However, after having done this, it doesn't seem like I am able to add web support to my project. Following Flutter's official instructions to enable web for a pre-existing project, I try to run `flutter create .` in the root directory of the project. When I do this I get the output:

`The Xcode project defines schemes: dev, prod You must specify a --flavor option to select one of the available schemes.`

So I try to run: `flutter create . --flavor=dev` and get `Multiple output directories specified. Try moving --flavor=dev to be immediately following create`

Soooo, I try: `flutter create --flavor=dev .` and get `Could not find an option named "flavor".`

Does anyone know how I can initialize web for this project? Thanks.

Comment: are you using different main files entry points?! If not, is not going to work on web. You should have a main_dev.dart and main_prod.dart (even more if you want more flavors)

Comment: I am not using different entry points, no. Is there a way I can create multiple entry points while not having to undo all the work I did to create flavors with `--flavor`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to do the following:

1. Goto root folder and rename manually `ios` folder temporarily to something like `ios1`
2. Goto terminal and make sure you are standing in root, then run this line:

   `flutter create --platforms=web .`
3. Return to project folder and rename back manually `ios1` to `ios`
4. Done