# flutter create . is failing with "You must specify a --flavor option"

Tags: flutter-web

I have an existing app I'm developing on mac and need to build a web version. As part of the flow for updating my app for the web, I type `flutter create .` from the project directory. When I do I get the error

```
The Xcode project defines schemes: dev, preprod, prod
You must specify a --flavor option to select one of the available schemes.
```

but `flutter create` does not have a `--flavor` option, so I'm stuck. :/

**EDIT:**
I ran `flutter create . -v` and got the output below

```
Command line invocation:
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -list

  User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

  Information about project "Runner":
    Targets:
      Runner

    Build Configurations:
      Debug-prod
      Debug-preprod
      Debug-dev
      Release-prod
      Release-preprod
      Release-dev
      Profile-prod
      Profile-preprod
      Profile-dev

    If no build configuration is specified and -scheme is not passed then "Release-prod" is used.

    Schemes:
      dev
      preprod
      prod

  [   +9 ms] The Xcode project defines schemes: dev, preprod, prod
  [  +15 ms] "flutter create" took 1,798ms.
  [   +5 ms] You must specify a --flavor option to select one of the available schemes.
```

So, I duplicated one of my schemes and named it `Release-prod` and ran the command again. I got the same error, but with `Release-prod` now listed. I then went into Xcode and disable all but one scheme, but am getting the same error with all three schemes listed. Is there somewhere else I can disable them? I'd rather not delete them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68268573/64505

Answer (score 0):

flutter create --platforms=windows,macos,linux (flavor name)